# Как назначить класс первому элементу?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap

```
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" ng-repeat='item in myData'>
    <div class="item active">
      <img ng-src="{{item.photoUrl}}" alt="pic">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <ul>
        <h3>{{item.description}}</h3>
            <li>{{item.instruction}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Есть карусель на bootstrap, первый элемент имеет класс "`active`", а следующие уже при клике его наследуют, таким образом и работает эта карусель. При `ng-repeat` я могу передать либо всем active либо не передать класс вообще.

Можно ли как то с помощью `filter` или другим способом выбрать 1 элемент `ng-repeat` и на него установить класс `active`, только на него.

Comment: вы хотите чтобы класс выставился только один раз при загрузке?

Comment: @Grundy только на 1й вставляемый элемент. Вот я загружаю на страницу 10 элементов, с помощью ng-repeat, нужно чтобы у 1го был класс 'active', а у остальных 9ти не было .

Comment: добавьте в `item` поле `activ` и проверяйте его.

Comment: @Grundy извини, не совсем понял как это реализовать, с angular знаком буквально пару дней. В контроллере проверку прописать? или может можно сделать фильтр на first-child и ему присвоить как то класс?

Comment: нет, в момент когда получили `myData` в контроллере делаете `myData[0].active = true`; и в разметке ` <div class="item" ng-class="{'active': item.active}">`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо огромное!

Comment: А почему тег ангуляр убрали?

Answer (score 2):

У ngRepeat есть свойство `$first`. Им можно воспользоваться 
Так в элемент, который будет повторяться нужно добавить следующую строку: `ng-class="{ 'acive': $first }"`

Так же нужно перенести ngRepeat в `<div class="item">`...

Код целиком:

```
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
    <div class="item" ng-repeat='item in myData' ng-class="{ 'acive': $first }">
      <img ng-src="{{item.photoUrl}}" alt="pic">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <ul>
        <h3>{{item.description}}</h3>
            <li>{{item.instruction}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов, хранить поле `active` в самом объекте `item`. И в зависимости от значения добавлять или убирать класс `active`.

```
<div class="item" ng-class="{'active': item.active}">
```

Установить его для первого элемента в `true` можно в момент получения данных

```
myData[0].active = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Еще как вариант в самом repeat сделать итерацию и, если `i===0`, то установить класс:
`ng-repeat="(i, item} in myData"`
`ng-class="{'active':i === 0}"`